# How to show content loading progress bar in a browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, web

I loaded this website https://www.teamwork.com/ on chrome browser and I can see a progres bar (a blue colored) below the address bar. anybody have an idea what is it ? this is progress bar of chrome or something this website made ?

Comment: Pace.js http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Progress bars can be made a number of ways. I'd recommend using pace.js, which is what teamwork.com is using - it's as dead easy as they come:

http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/

Comment: Looks like the link is dead now.

Answer (score 0):

It's not specific to chrome.

This is a script used to show the loading of images in the page.

The plugin used here is Pace : http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/